# writing to hdfs error: Not enough replicas was chosen. Reason: {NO_REQUIRED_STORAGE_TYPE=1}

Tags: hadoop, hdfs, namenode, datanode

I encountered the problem similar to this:

[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52809233/failed-to-place-enough-replicas-expected-size-is-1-but-only-0-storage-types-can](https://stackoverflow.com)

---

my name node logs in $HADOOP_HOME/logs/ while the storage policy is set to ALL_SSD:

```
2023-05-21 09:17:31,380 DEBUG org.apache.hadoop.net.NetworkTopology: Choosing random from 4 available nodes on node /default-rack, scope=/default-rack, excludedScope=null, excludeNodes=[192.168.132.41:9866]. numOfDatanodes=5.
2023-05-21 09:17:31,380 DEBUG org.apache.hadoop.net.NetworkTopology: nthValidToReturn is 0
2023-05-21 09:17:31,380 DEBUG org.apache.hadoop.net.NetworkTopology: Chosen node 192.168.132.44:9866 from first random
2023-05-21 09:17:31,380 DEBUG org.apache.hadoop.net.NetworkTopology: chooseRandom returning 192.168.132.44:9866
2023-05-21 09:17:31,380 DEBUG org.apache.hadoop.net.NetworkTopology: Failed to find datanode (scope="" excludedScope="/default-rack"). numOfDatanodes=0
2023-05-21 09:17:31,380 DEBUG org.apache.hadoop.net.NetworkTopology: No node to choose.
2023-05-21 09:17:31,380 DEBUG org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.blockmanagement.BlockPlacementPolicy: [
  Datanode None is not chosen since required storage types are unavailable  for storage type DISK.
2023-05-21 09:17:31,380 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.blockmanagement.BlockPlacementPolicy: Not enough replicas was chosen. Reason: {NO_REQUIRED_STORAGE_TYPE=1}
2023-05-21 09:17:31,380 DEBUG org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.blockmanagement.BlockPlacementPolicy: Failed to choose remote rack (location = ~/default-rack), fallback to local rack
org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.blockmanagement.BlockPlacementPolicy$NotEnoughReplicasException: 
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.blockmanagement.BlockPlacementPolicyDefault.chooseRandom(BlockPlacementPolicyDefault.java:914)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.blockmanagement.BlockPlacementPolicyDefault.chooseRemoteRack(BlockPlacementPolicyDefault.java:774)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.blockmanagement.BlockPlacementPolicyDefault.chooseTargetInOrder(BlockPlacementPolicyDefault.java:566)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.blockmanagement.BlockPlacementPolicyDefault.chooseTarget(BlockPlacementPolicyDefault.java:478)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.blockmanagement.BlockPlacementPolicyDefault.chooseTarget(BlockPlacementPolicyDefault.java:524)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.blockmanagement.BlockPlacementPolicyDefault.chooseTarget(BlockPlacementPolicyDefault.java:350)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.blockmanagement.BlockPlacementPolicyDefault.chooseTarget(BlockPlacementPolicyDefault.java:170)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.blockmanagement.BlockPlacementPolicyDefault.chooseTarget(BlockPlacementPolicyDefault.java:195)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.blockmanagement.BlockManager.chooseTarget4NewBlock(BlockManager.java:2307)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSDirWriteFileOp.chooseTargetForNewBlock(FSDirWriteFileOp.java:294)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem.getAdditionalBlock(FSNamesystem.java:2960)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNodeRpcServer.addBlock(NameNodeRpcServer.java:904)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocolPB.ClientNamenodeProtocolServerSideTranslatorPB.addBlock(ClientNamenodeProtocolServerSideTranslatorPB.java:593)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocol.proto.ClientNamenodeProtocolProtos$ClientNamenodeProtocol$2.callBlockingMethod(ClientNamenodeProtocolProtos.java)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.ProtobufRpcEngine2$Server$ProtoBufRpcInvoker.call(ProtobufRpcEngine2.java:604)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.ProtobufRpcEngine2$Server$ProtoBufRpcInvoker.call(ProtobufRpcEngine2.java:572)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.ProtobufRpcEngine2$Server$ProtoBufRpcInvoker.call(ProtobufRpcEngine2.java:556)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RPC$Server.call(RPC.java:1093)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$RpcCall.run(Server.java:1043)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$RpcCall.run(Server.java:971)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:422)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1878)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler.run(Server.java:2976)
2023-05-21 09:17:31,380 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.StateChange: BLOCK* allocate blk_1113051428_39314554, replicas=192.168.132.43:9866, 192.168.132.41:9866, 192.168.132.44:9866 for /Hakim/archive_players/partitions=1/date=2023-05-20/part-00003-dfce3f68-b1f5-45eb-8f91-43da0ae42139.c000.snappy.parquet
```

this error log occurs repeatedly for ever write operation  until the name node crashes.

I'v done whatever I can, but still exists.
I'v tried all storage policies of ONE_SSD, ALL_SSD,HOT, COLD

when I run `lsblk`

this is the result on all nodes(namenode and all datanodes):
[image: lsblk result on datanode]

`/hdfs` partition is the location of data nodes and namenode data in all cluster nodes.

the `lvm` type shown in picture below consist of physical SSDs:

`lsblk -d -n -o name,rota`   the result is:

[image: lvm contining disks]

---

my hdfs-site.xml configuration:

```
<configuration>
        <property>
                <name>dfs.replication.min</name>
                <value>1</value>
        </property>
        <property>
                <name>dfs.replication.max</name>
                <value>3</value>
        </property>

        <property>
                <name>dfs.name.dir</name>
                <value>file:///hdfs/hadoop_data/hdfs/nameNode</value>
        </property>

        <property>
                <name>dfs.data.dir</name>
                <value>file:///hdfs/hadoop_data/hdfs/dataNode</value>
        </property>
        <property>
                <name>dfs.permissions</name>
                <value>false</value>
                <name>dfs.namenode.acls.enabled</name>
                <value>false</value>
        </property>
        <property>
                <name>dfs.webhdfs.enabled</name>
                <value>true</value>
        </property>
        <property>
                <name>dfs.storage.policy.enabled</name>
                <value>true</value>
        </property>
        <property>
                <name>hadoop.security.hdfs.umask-mode</name>
                <value>000</value>
        </property>
        <property>
                <name>dfs.blocksize</name>
                <value>536870912</value>
        </property>

</configuration>
```

my core-site.xml configuration:

```
<configuration>
        <property>
                <name>fs.defaultFS</name>
                <value>hdfs://192.168.132.37:9000</value>
        </property>
        <property>
                <name>hadoop.tmp.dir</name>
                <value>/hdfs/hadoop_data/hdfs/tempDir</value>
        </property>
        <property>
                <name>dfs.permissions</name>
                <value>false</value>
        </property>
        <property>
                <name>hadoop.proxyuser.simra.groups</name>
                <value>*</value>
        </property>
        <property>
                <name>hadoop.proxyuser.simra.hosts</name>
                <value>*</value>
        </property>
                <property>
                <name>hadoop.proxyuser.server.hosts</name>
                <value>*</value>
        </property>
        <property>
                <name>hadoop.proxyuser.server.groups</name>
                <value>*</value>
                <name>hadoop.user.group.static.mapping.overrides</name>
                <value>dr.who=dr.who,user1,user2,user3,user4,user5,user6;</value>
        </property>
```

checking the datanode ports:

[image: data node ports]

my namenode web ui overview:

[image: name node webui overview]

[image: data node status]

---

### update: there's a point, when I wanto to write a parquet to hdfs using pyspark, the Df is partitioned to n files based on partitioning rules of pyspark(as default n= spark worker cores), some of these  files are written successfully, and some others encounter that error.

I'v spent more than a month and no result, I'm so confused what to do.
Any one can help?

Comment: Do you have any firewall rules that may block required ports?

Comment: NO, all then nodes are in the same network without firewall. also, when iI telent the namenode 9000 it's Ok, and in the name node I have telnet to data nodes.

Answer (score 1):

I encountered a similar issue. Though I don't OP has this issue, it may help others coming across this question.

In my case, HDFS had been configured to use 2 storage dirs, with a storage policy restricting a specific HDFS path to a specific storage dir.

```
# in hdfs-site.xml:
<property>
  <name>dfs.datanode.data.dir</name>
  <value>file://data-0, [SSD]file://data-1</value>
</property>
```

HDFS writes failed because the disk holding the first data dir was full (only this dir was allowed due to the `hdfs storagepolicies` that we had). Note that the other data dir was not full, so the HDFS UI showed a disk capacity of less than 100% (which was pretty confusing).

Answer (score 1):

For me it helped to set dfs.use.dfs.network.topology = false. As far as I have understood, hadoop/hdfs is rack-ware. It tries to not write the same block to the same node, and to no more than two nodes in the same rack. And therefore distributing the data across multiple racks. I run a very simplistic hdfs in a single Zone, so I do not care about the topology at all.